# pandas: how to do piecewise calculation based on condition of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
symbol    Time     Volume    cumVolume   group ...                                                 
00001       0       100         100        0   ...
00001       3       100         200        0   ...
00001       7      -200           0        0   ...
00001      12      -100        -100        1   ...
00001      13      -200        -300        1   ...
00001      18       300           0        1   ...      
00002       0      -100        -100        2   ...  
00002       4      -100        -200        2   ...  
00002       7       100        -100        2   ...  
00002      13       300         200        2   ...  
00002      15       300         500        3   ...
```

I want to do the calculation for each symbol's sub-dataframe divided by `group`. For instance, I can see the dataframe like this:

```
symbol    Time     Volume    cumVolume   group ...                                                 
00001       0       100         100        0   ...
00001       3       100         200        0   ...
00001       7      -200           0        0   ...
----------------------------------------------------
00001      12      -100        -100        1   ...
00001      13      -200        -300        1   ...
00001      18       300           0        1   ...  
----------------------------------------------------    
00002       0      -100        -100        2   ...  
00002       4      -100        -200        2   ...  
00002       7       100        -100        2   ...  
00002      13       300         200        2   ...  
----------------------------------------------------
00002      15       300         500        3   ...
```

the calculation rule is: `Volume` * `Time to section end`

For example, for the first section:  (100)*(7-0) + (100)*(7-3) + (-200)*(7-7)

For the second section: (-100)*(18-12) + (-200)*(18-13) + (300)*(18-18)

I am struggling with how to get the `Time to section end` variable. Could you give me some hints or solutions?

Comment: You state you want to compute "Volume * Time to section end".  Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'to section end'?  Are you looking for Volume * Time by row or Volume * groupby(Time).sum()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we want to calculate this value for each `"group"`, so we need to `df.groupby("group")`. Then, for each group, you can get the "end time" using `df_group.max()`. Now, to calculate "time to section end" we just substract the values: `df_group["Time"].max() - df_group["Time"]`. This works because is a "vectorized" operation. Finally, you can multiply the volume and then add everything using `.sum()`:

```
for group, df_group in df.groupby("group"):
    result = (df_group["Volume"] * (df_group["Time"].max() - df_group["Time"])).sum()
    print(group, result)
```